# JSP displays HTML source code in IE11; Websphere 7.0

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue with displaying JSP page in IE11 browser. The pages are displaying properly in IE8, IE10 (compact-view) and IE (enterprise mode). But, in IE11 native version the page is showing the HTML code instead of rendered JSP page.

Few points :

1. This JSP is called from a servlet.
2. In servlet, I have added a line before dispatch  `response.setHeader("content-type", "text/html")`. The same in JSP page is also already tried but not fixed.
3. `"meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"` is also tried but not fixed.
4. The same JSP code works fine even in IE11 from the IBM's Rational Application Developper (IRAD) tool. I see this issue only when I deploy this code in 'real' Websphere application server.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does you page have a proper DOCYTYPE, do you declare charset?  Also, I think the header should be "Content-Type" (case-sensitive).